# local costmap empty in ros navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ar-kinect, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a Kinect on a mobile robot, where I use the package [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan)  to publish a fake laser in the topic */scan* for the navigation stack. The problem is that I am not able to see any obstacle in the local costmap. I have tried all the solutions, checking the maximum and minimum obstacle range, etc. When I do `rostopic info /scan`, I see the following subscritions:

```
Subscribers: 
 * /rviz (http://192.168.1.25:46119/)
 * /amcl (http://192.168.1.25:40276/)
```

Should I see any other node subscribed to this topic, like the move_base node? May be this the problem?
I am quite lost, so any help would be really appreciated! The .yam configuration files about the navigation are just the same as described in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup).

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259651/local-costmap-empty-in-ros-navigation/) by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-20**:
Sure, if you want scan data in the costmap, the costmap should subscribe to scan. Please paste all your costmap configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, thanks for answering!
I could solve the problem, and I don't know exactly the reason. What I think is: although I changed the values in the configuration files of the costmap, they were not uploaded when I restarted the move_base launch. This is, some of these new values in the configuration files were not taking into account when I relaunched the move_base node.

After restarting the computer, everything was working fine, so my guess is that some of the parameters were taking previous configurations. Could this be possible? Maybe this wasn't actually happening and I am wrong. Then I have no clue about what solved the problem :)

---

Originally posted by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) with karma: 18 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2017-06-21**:
Maybe you just need to restart roscore?